# looking for tool(s) for making diagrams with

Tags: propositional-logic

I am looking for some tool to create symbolic logic derivation diagrams with horizontal and vertical scope line and sub derivations.  Then I want to be able to add them to a word document.  Word doesn't appear to make creating the diagram possible.

Thank You

Comment: This is a question for math SE, maybe, but not philosophy.

Comment: I am taking philosophy 9.  How is philosophy 9 math and not philosophy?

Comment: Technical questions on symbolic logic are more suitable for Math SE, regardless of which course they come up in. This one I am not even sure is that, it is more of a question about editor features.

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the checkmark to reward the user!